# Database Mail not sending

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I'm trying to send email using the DatabaseMail on SQL Server 2008, I can see my emails setting in the

```
msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems
```

But they just sit there, I get no error messages. 
I've checked I have rights to use the DatabaseMail by using the following TSQL:

```
EXEC msdb.sys.sp_helprolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole';
```

And I have also run

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';
```

which shows the length as the number of emails I've tried to send but the Status is still showing as Inactive.

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Is the profile you are using PUBLIC ? ALso, is this on a stand alone server or clustered ?

Comment: it is Public, the server is on a cluster.

Comment: EXEC msdb.sys.sp_helprolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole'; lists the MemberName as guest, is this normal?

Comment: I had experienced the same problem few years ago. I had blogged it [Strange issue with database mail in clustered environment - not working tried everything](http://sqlquest.blogspot.com/2010/01/strange-issue-with-database-mail-in.html#axzz356twyOw2)

Comment: Hi Kin, unfortunately I do not have the config setting

Comment: Has this DBMail (on this sql instance) ever sent an email successfully? If not, you may need to look into the DBMail configuration.

Comment: Are you trying to send attachment with the mail?

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue, for me it got resolved by installing .NET 3.5 and 4.5

Comment: Yep. I had this issue as well and fixed it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. It came out that this is known issue. 
[FIX: SQL Server 2016 Database Mail does not work on a computer that does not have the .NET Framework 3.5 installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186435/fix-sql-server-2016-database-mail-does-not-work-on-a-computer-that-doe).

Comment: Note that the original question was posted in summer of 2014, so the problem was presumably not this one. This may admittedly help others who are using Sql 2016, but wouldn't have helped the OP.

Comment: Right. My problem was not on SQL 2008. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Up to you. It does provide unique info (the link to the MS article), and the original question didn't specify a version, so people having 2016 problems could find this question and your answer; that makes it useful (and I didn't downvote it, you'll note :-) ). Just wanted to note that the OP was having some other problem.